# Definition of limit of a sequence of ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Could you guys please help me understand (intuitively) the definition of limit of a sequence? This is the definition I have:

[image]

I'm trying to visualize what's going on, I imagine two parallel lines, lower one representing the domain $\lambda$ (which is a limit ordinal) whose elements are $\gamma$, and the upper one representing the codomain, the line containing all the $f(\gamma)=\beta_{\gamma}$.

Now the definition says:
"We say that the ordinal $\alpha$ is the limit of the sequence.." where should I put this $\alpha$? Is it part of the domain or of the codomain? I think it's part of the codomain so I put a dot on the codomain line to represent this $\alpha$.

"..if for each $\delta<\alpha$.."
 since $\alpha$ was on the codomain line I put this $\delta$ to the left of this $\alpha$ on this same line.

"..there is some $\gamma_{\delta}<\lambda$.."
 since we're talking about ordinal numbers $<$ means $\in$, therefore I put $\gamma_{\delta}$ on the domain line,

"..such that for all $\gamma$ with $\gamma_{\delta}<\gamma<\lambda$.."
 this means, such that for every number between this last dot we drew and $\lambda$ (which is the last number of the domain)

"..$\delta<\beta_{\gamma}\leq\alpha$"
 this means there is some number of the sequence between $\alpha$ and $\delta$

Is representing this definition in this way correct?

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct. It gets a bit dodgy at the end. First, $\lambda$ is not the last ordinal in the domain, it *is* the domain. Since these are ordinals that means it is the first number not in the domain. More importantly, the last part should be "*every* [corresponding] number of the sequence is between $\alpha$ and $\delta$". If we imagine $\gamma$ moving along the line from 0 towards $\lambda$ then the corresponding $\beta_\gamma$ can jump around anywhere on the codomain line to start with, but there comes a point after which it stays above $\delta$, and that applies however close we choose $\delta$ to $\alpha$. (It is very analogous to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition in analysis.)